# How to properly handle 'despine' function to avoid error message

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib

I have been using `despine(plt.gca())` as a tool to plot my time series data as demonstrated below:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

date_rng = pd.date_range(start='1/2015', end='1/2019', freq='M')

#Let’s create an example data frame with the timestamp data and look at the first 5
df = pd.DataFrame(date_rng, columns=['date'])
df['data'] = np.random.randint(0,100,size=(len(date_rng)))
df.head()

df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
df = df.set_index('datetime')
df.drop(['date'], axis=1, inplace=True)
df.head()

# we visualize the data:
df.plot(lw=1.5)
despine(plt.gca())
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.ylabel('Series');
```

The above python code gives the below error message

```
NameError: name 'despine' is not defined
```

if I import seaborn as below:

```
mport seaborn as sns
df.plot(lw=1.5)
sns.despine(plt.gca())
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.ylabel('Series');
```

it will produce the error below:

```
'AxesSubplot' object is not iterable
```

though the plot is made, but I will prefer there is no error message at all. This error message keep coming each time I use the particular line of code.

Please help me figure out what is wrong with despine(plt.gca()). I am running this code on python 3

Comment: What is `despine`? Do you mean `seaborn.despine`?

Comment: @DavidG yes, seaborn.despine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't defined any function called `despine`, nor have you imported any modules with that function defined within it. Assuming you want to use [`seaborn.despine`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.despine.html), you need to import the module and then access the despine function:

```
import seaborn as sns

# Your code here

sns.despine(ax=plt.gca())
```

Comment: 'AxesSubplot' object is not iterable

Comment: @DanielJames Sorry, missed the `ax=`. I've updated my answer, it should work now